# print only the unique values from first column by comparing two columns in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a text file with example
(two columns separated with a :)

if the first columns first row is repeated again then dont consider it and give the output

11:22

33:44

55:66

55:77

my desired output should be

11:22

33:44

Answer (score 1):

```
sort file | uniq --unique --check-chars=2
```

I'm making two assumptions:

- it's okay to change the row order (sort)
- the first column will always be two characters wide

Answer (score 1):

For excluding the lines that have repetition of **first column only**:

```
sort file | uniq -u -w 1
```

For excluding the lines that have repetition of **first field** when **delimited by colon**:

```
cut -d: -f1 file | sort | uniq -u
```

In the two cases, we need to `sort` the file before piping the output to `uniq` (as `uniq` works on adjacent matching lines). Then do `uniq` with some options.

From `uniq` man page:

```
-u:     only print unique lines
-w N:   compare no more than N characters in lines
```

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: Have been edited to fit the correct answer.